# IE not showing content

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

On my website I have a popup which is triggered by button click and which works fine. This popup features a sign up form and the following js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery("input#submit").click(function () {
        jQuery('#response p').empty().append("<img src='ajax-loader.gif' />");
        var name = jQuery("#name").val();
        var email = jQuery("#email").val();
        var dataString = '&name=' + name + '&email=' + email;
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "popupmailer.php",
            data: dataString,
            type: "GET",
            success: function (responseText) {
                jQuery('#response p').empty().append(responseText);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
-->
</script>
```

This seems to work fine, however once I try this in IE the popup does not show up at all. I've tried to troubleshoot this a little bit and once I remove the above mentioned code the popup shows up again in IE.

Is someone able to help me and determine what is wrong here in order to make this work? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using developer tool in IE? It might show the cause of the issue. Also , you can add breakpoints there to isolate the issue.

Comment: This is probably not related, but your `dataString` doesn't need to begin with a `&` (which should technically be a `?`, but jQuery will prepend that for you).

Comment: Try removing "return false;"

Answer (score 1):

You should try with `form submit`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function () {
   jQuery("form").submit(function (e) {
     jQuery('#response p').empty().append("<img src='ajax-loader.gif' />");

     var dataString = $('form').serialize(); //<---just serialize the form this will make a dataString you want.

     jQuery.ajax({
        url: "popupmailer.php",
        data: dataString,
        type: "GET",
        success: function (responseText) {
            jQuery('#response p').html(responseText); //<--use .html() here
        }
     });
     return false;
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Jay! I've just implemented you method as a result though it seems that the form now does not work in chrome / ff and still ie

Comment: This will serialize the whole form, instead of just the items he wants to pass (if that matters)

Comment: @DaveMilan: It could be because Jai used `$` instead of `jQuery`; he should have been consistent, but may have made a hasty error

Comment: @DaveMilan do you have a form name or id?

Comment: I am using Jay's method now with all jQuery and edited the $ - it seems to be back working now for Chrome and FF but still no luck on IE. @Jay: No it currently does not have any ID. Should I attribute one?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
jQuery('#response p').empty().html(responseText);
```

instead of

```
jQuery('#response p').empty().append(responseText);
```

Comment: Thank you very much - I've tried to change it to your method but it's still not working in IE.